# CSS Changing position of div to absolute ruins the layout

Tags: html, css

I have a div(bottom) at the bottom of my page.

It has a background image and another div(bottomnav) with an unordered list for the navigation.

When I change bottomnav's position to absolute the entire bottom div gets shifted up into the div above it. also, i have another div called cc. that one i can change to absolute without any problems.

This is my code:

html

```
<div id="bottom">
<div id="bottomnav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
<div id="cc">©2014 European Homemakers</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
#bottom
{
background-image:url(../Images/home_bottom.png);
width: 960px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
min-height: 100px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:relative;

}

#bottomnav
{
font-size: 20px;



}
#bottomnav ul {
list-style-type: none; 
height:auto;

}

#bottomnav li
{
display:inline; 
padding:20px;   
}

#bottomnav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FF9200;
}
#cc
{
text-align:right;
color: #FF9200;
position:absolute;
bottom: 5px;
right: 5px;
font-size:20px;
}
```

Im pretty new to web design so Im not sure why changing bottomnav to absolute changes the layout.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I would like to be able to have bottomnav have position absolute so that i can move it around within the bottom div

Comment: I can do that with cc but it doesnt work with bottomnav

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbwEf Are you expecting this kind of output?

Comment: yes but without having the bottom div shift up, thats whats happening to me.

Comment: However in this case its not good way to set element using position: absolute. You can do it using float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/hzLW4/1/)**

First of all you are not closing **#bottom** `div`, Secondly as **#bottom** is `position: relative` so any thing inside it will be absolute relative to this `div`. Therefore, remove footer `div` out of it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="bottomnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
<div id="cc">©2014 European Homemakers</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bottom {
    background-image:url(../Images/home_bottom.png);
    width: 960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}
#bottomnav {
    font-size: 20px;
}
#bottomnav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height:auto;
}
#bottomnav li {
    display:inline;
    padding:20px;
}
#bottomnav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF9200;
}
#cc {
    color: #FF9200;
    font-size:20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting for footer to always be at bottom regards the content, then this will help you.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/full/lmrgD)

You need to change you structure.